# Comparing the inside of a multidimensional array with a simple array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to compare the 'criteria' array inside this multidimensional array

```
   Array
(
    [8399] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 1
            [criteria] => Array
                (
                    [Marime] => 2
                    [Suport] => 6
                    [Pret] => 3.80
                )

        )

)
```

With this array:

```
Array
(
    [Marime] => 1
    [Suport] => 7
    [Pret] => 6.20
)
```

All this because I want to be able to do something like

```
if($array1 !== $array2){}
```

Any help would be appreciated , thank you!

Comment: `if($array1[8399]['criteria'] !== $array2){}`

Comment: use  arra_diff whern you compare two array .

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution...

```
$m_array = array(
        8399 => array(
            'qty' => 1,
            'criteria' => array(
                'Marime' => 2,
                'Suport' => 6,
                'Pret' => 3.80
                )
            )
        );
$array = array('Marime' => 1,'Suport' => 7, 'Pret' => 6.20);

foreach($m_array as $row){
    if(($row['criteria']['Marime']==$array['Marime'])&&($row['criteria']['Suport']==$array['Suport'])&&($row['criteria']['Pret']==$array['Pret'])){
        //type your code here....
    }
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($m_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code below to compare the arrays.

```
if(($aray1[8399]['criteria']['Marime']==$aray2['Marime'])&&($aray1[8399]['criteria']['Suport']==$aray2['Suport'])&&($aray1[8399]['criteria']['Pret']==$aray2['Pret'])){

    echo 'Your output'; 
}
```

[Click here for demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ae54d2a43e69d5ee793040a9a2946c739126023c)

Comment: You can set condition as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I used someone's answer that got deleted:

```
if($products[$product->getId()]['criteria'] == $criteria)){

}
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score -2):

$result = array_diff($array1[8399]['criteria'],$array2);

print_R($result);

try this code it will display the diffrence in both array values

Comment: Hann... Code Kitthe hai?

Comment: <?php 
$result = array_diff($array1[8399]['criteria'],$array2);

print_R($result);

?>

try this code it will display the diffrence in both array values